# Dynamically add listbox columns based on columns in an Access Database?

Tags: sql, vb.net, listbox, ms-access-2010

I would like to do a populate a column in my listbox for each field in my Access Database.

Right now I have to manually add the field:

```
QUERBOX.Columns.Add("Requestor Name", 200, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
```

How can I adapt my code below to automatically add columns each time I run the sub?

```
      Dim queryString As String = "SELECT * FROM Table1;"





    Dim connection As OleDbConnection
    Dim command As OleDbCommand
    Dim data_reader As OleDbDataReader








querbox.clear


    connection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\apt.accdb")
    connection.Open()


    command = New OleDbCommand(queryString, connection)
    data_reader = Command.ExecuteReader



    If data_reader.HasRows Then
        While data_reader.Read
            Dim newitem As New ListViewItem()
            newitem.Text = data_reader.GetValue(0) 'first column
            newitem.SubItems.Add(data_reader.GetValue(1)) 'second column
            QUERBOX.Items.Add(newitem)

        End While
    End If
```

Comment: A listbox is suboptimal for columns.  A DataGridView will automatically add columns and display the data for you

Comment: Nice, it even had a wizard to walk me through it. Already set up. Fantastic, I guess I was searching for the wrong thing all this time. Will use datagrid view from now on.

Answer (score 0):

As Plutonix suggested in comments, a DataGridView would probably be best suited, but for the sake of answering the question here's how I've done something similar:

```
connection.Open()
'' Fill a DataTable with all of the Column schema for the given table of 'Table1'
Dim schemaTable As DataTable = connection.GetSchema("Columns", New String() {Nothing, Nothing, "Table1", Nothing})
'' Iterate through each column in the Schema Table
For i = 0 To schemaTable.Rows.Count - 1 Step 1
    '' Declare a new item for the list
    Dim newItem As New ListViewItem()
    newItem.Text = schemaTable.Rows(i)!COLUMN_NAME.ToString()
    newItem.SubItems.Add(schemaTable.Rows(i)!COLUMN_NAME.ToString()
    '' Add new item to the interface
    QUERBOX.Items.Add(newItem)
Next
connection.Close()
```

This has helped me in projects where the user is familiar with the database structure and may need to select the fieldname as part of the business logic. For example, allowing someone with little database knowledge to standardize the records within a given field.